# boost:exception_detail::clone_impl

Tags: ros, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get my create 2 up and running using an Autonomy Lab driver.  I am using Indigo 14.04  on an Intel UP board.  I get the following error:

```
NODES
  /
    ca_driver (ca_driver/ca_driver)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[ca_driver-1]: started with pid [3217]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [3218]
[ INFO] [1473635274.333406872]: [CREATE] "CREATE_2" selected
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  open: No such file or directory
[ca_driver-1] process has died [pid 3217, exit code -6, cmd /home/jon/create_ws/devel/lib/ca_driver/ca_driver __name:=ca_driver __log:=/home/jon/.ros/log/7a477552-7870-11e6-8e2b-0007323c63d0/ca_driver-1.log].
log file: /home/jon/.ros/log/7a477552-7870-11e6-8e2b-0007323c63d0/ca_driver-1*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243609/boost:exception_detail::clone_impl/) by [jonK](https://answers.ros.org/users/27956/jonk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your Create 2 is not appearing as the default device name `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Power on the Create, connect the serial cable, and check to see that the device is correct. You can do this by running `ls /dev` before and after connecting the Create and identifying the new device that appear in the list. Then, try modifying the value of the parameter `dev` in the file `create_2.launch` to match the listed device.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonK](https://answers.ros.org/users/27956/jonk/) on 2016-09-14**:
After I asked the question, I went back and wiped my drive and reinstalled Indigo 14.04, ROS, and the Autonomy Lab driver. I was then able to connect to my Create 2. Apparently, I did something during the previous install that confused the operating system. Thank you for your response

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-12-01**:
I got a similar problem I just reconnected the roomba to my laptop via a serial cable and I did this as long as this appeard when doing **lsusb** in a terminal.:
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC